# How to run an specific test case in the selected environment in SoapUI

Tags: api, groovy, automation, soapui, ready-api

I have multiple Environment and a lot of test cases, but not all test cases are needed to be run in all environment. Is there a way to run only an specific test cases from a test suite based on the selected Environment.

For Example
If I select Environment1, it will run the following test cases

```
TC0001
TC0002
TC0003
TC0004
TC0005
```

If I select Environment2, it will run only the following test cases

```
TC0001
TC0003
TC0005
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be different solution to achieve this since you have multiple environments i.e., pro software being used.

I would achieve the solution using `Test Suite`'s **Setup Script**:

- Create `Test Suite` level custom property. Use the same name as your environment name. For instance, `DEV` is the environment defined, use the same as test suite property name and provide the list of values separated by comma as value for that property, say **TC1, TC2** etc.,
- Similarly defined other environments and its values as well.
- Copy the below script in `Setup Script` for the **test suite** and execute the script which *enables* or *disables* the test cases according to the **environment and property value**

**Test Suite's Setup Script**

```
/**
* This is soapui's Setup Script
* which enables / disables required
* test cases based on the user list
* for that specific environment
**/
def disableTestCase(testCaze) {
    testCaze.disabled = true
}

def enableTestCase(testCaze) {
    testCaze.disabled = false
}

def getEnvironmentSpecificList(def testSuite) {
    def currentEnv = testSuite.project.activeEnvironment.NAME
    def enableList = testSuite.getPropertyValue(currentEnv).split(',').collect { it.trim()}
    log.info "List of test for enable: ${enableList}"
    enableList
}

def userList = getEnvironmentSpecificList(testSuite)
testSuite.testCaseList.each { kase ->
    if (userList.contains(kase.name)) {
        enableTestCase(kase)
    } else {
        disableTestCase(kase)
    }
}
```

Other way to achieve this is using `Event` feature of ReadyAPI, you may use `TestRunListener.beforeRun()` and filter the test case whether to execute or ignore.

**EDIT:**
If you are using `ReadyAPI`, then you can the new feature called `tag` the test cases. A test case can be tagged with multiple values and you can execute tests using specific tags. In this case, you may not needed to have the `setup script` as that is for the open source edition. Refer [documentation](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/structure/suites/window/cases/tags) for more details.
This solution is only specific to `Pro` software and Open Source edition does have this `tag` feature.

Comment: How can you do it in Event.. I'm using a Pro SoapUI

Comment: It would be good if you try the given solution and accept it as answer if helpful. Event way, does not seems to be straight forward not much elegant.

Comment: I encountered an error in this line def userList = getEnvironmentSpecificList (testSuite).. The error is this [link] (https://www.screencast.com/t/d4twV54IOduU)

Comment: You are not following the instructions. Are you? Please use `Setup Script` of test suite. that is neither supposed to be in a separate test case nor groovy script. Please see the screen shot of the same here - https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/working-with-scripts.html. You should double click on `Core - All Markets` to find the `Setup Script`. Have you defined test suite properties too?

Comment: By the way, there is minor issue found in the script, updated answer. So, request to try the updated script.

Comment: @raiqee, have you run this solution? do you have any question? if that worked, would you mind accepting it as answer?

Comment: @rao can i use above script in soapui os?